# C# WPF - Get data from a web page via button click and paste into text box

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, copy, paste

I am stuck at trying to get a specific set of data from a web page via a button click, and then paste that value into a separate text box. I haven't found much on the topic that was of much use and was wondering if anyone could steer me in the right direction.

```
    private void refresh_goblin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string downloadString = client.DownloadString("http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/Ensouled_goblin_head/viewitem?obj=13448");
```

Above is a code excerpt from one of the buttons I'm working on. As a simple test, I have taken the URL of the website I want and stored it to a variable. If anyone could help show me how to paste this value into one of my text boxes so I can see how it's done that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to have a `TextBox` or `TextBlock` or similar control on your form. Then, in your method, set the `Text` property of the control to `downloadString`.

For example, if you've created a `TextBox` and named it "myTextbox", the code would look like this:

```
private void refresh_goblin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string downloadString = client.DownloadString("http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/Ensouled_goblin_head/viewitem?obj=13448");
    this.myTextbox.Text = downloadString;
}
```

Comment: This did it for me! I assumed it was something simple, set it to the text box I declared in my XAML. Thanks!